# Using Angular $translate on Labels with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, angular-translate

I have a Canvas element using a Chart.js graph. I set the chart-labels to my custom model.months in my controller.

```
<canvas id="line" ng-show="model.showActuals" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="[graph.Data]" chart-options="standardOptions" chart-labels="model.months" chart-series="['Series']" chart-colors="['#0078D7']"></canvas>
```

This is my controller logic:

```
$scope.model.months = ['MONTH_JANUARY', 'MONTH_FEBRUARY', 'MONTH_MARCH', 'MONTH_APRIL', 'MONTH_MAY', 'MONTH_JUNE', 'MONTH_JULY', 'MONTH_AUGUST', 'MONTH_SEPTEMBER', 'MONTH_OCTOBER', 'MONTH_NOVEMBER', 'MONTH_DECEMBER'];
$translate($scope.model.months).then(function (translatedValue) {
 $scope.model.months = translatedValue; });
```

When debugging, my model.months doesn't get translated. **We are using a Json file that has translated values for all the months**. But The result is:

[image: model.months result]

and finally I get a bunch of Chart.js errors that I have no idea what it's trying to do:

[image: chart.js errors]

Anyone familiar with using Angular Translate with Chart.js? I'm stumped.